# Is there a winning strategy for Losing chess?

Tags: strategy, chess-variants, losing-chess

Losing chess has been [proven](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/~watkins/LOSING_CHESS/) to be a win for white, with the opening move `1. e3`

The proof consists of a number of huge game trees which show that each variation must end in a white win, but is there a winning **strategy** for white, which can be used to force a win in a game without needing to memorise the entire game tree?

Answer (score 4):

One useful tactic is to try, as far as possible, to leave exactly one of your units en prise. That forces your opponent to capture that unit next. So to a large extent you're in control (and are losing units). By contrast, if you were not so careful as to which units of yours were en prise, then if ever two or more of them were, then your opponent can choose which of them to capture next, and thus keeps more control.